# Futures generated by ThreadPoolExecutor do not behave asynchronously

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I want to create a list of futures running on ThreadPoolExecutor, then display each one of them as soon as they finist evaluating.

The expected result is: each of 0, 2, 6, 12 will printed every 3 seconds.

However, I'm getting a result only after 12 seconds and the numbers are displayed simulatenously.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

def fnc(x, y):
    time.sleep(3)
    return x*y

futures = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    for i in range(0, 4):
        print(f"Submitting {i}")
        futures += [executor.submit(fnc, i, i+1)]

for f in futures:
    print(f.result())
```

Comment: You don't print the results until **all** threads have terminated - i.e., outside of the ThreadPoolExecutor Work Manager code block

Comment: Setting max_workers=1 makes no sense in this case. Either remove it or set it to a value >= 4

Comment: It's just code for testing the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Build your list of submitted futures then use *as_completed()* to know when a thread has finished and its result is available.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import time

def fnc(x, y):
    time.sleep(3)
    return x*y

futures = []

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for i in range(0, 4):
        print(f"Submitting {i}")
        futures += [executor.submit(fnc, i, i+1)]
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        print(future.result())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `result` method on each future outside the `ThreadPoolExecutor` context manager, when you exit, it, it calls the `__exit__` method:

```py
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    self.shutdown(wait=True)
    return False
```

The `shutdown` method signature is:

```py
shutdown(self, wait=True, *, cancel_futures=False)
```

And the docs says:

```
Args:
     wait: If True then shutdown will not return until all running
           futures have finished executing and the resources used by the
           executor have been reclaimed.
     cancel_futures: If True then shutdown will cancel all pending
           futures. Futures that are completed or running will not be
           cancelled.
```

We can see that by default it will wait until all running futures and their resources have stopped running as well, and that `cancel_futures` is by default getting the value `False`, thus we are **not** canceling pending futures.

We can prove it by changing the `fnc` to print the values instead of returning them, and do nothing after the `ThreadPoolExecutor` context manager block:

```py
def fnc(x, y):
    time.sleep(3)
    print(x * y)


futures = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    for i in range(0, 4):
        print(f"Submitting {i}")
        futures += [executor.submit(fnc, i, i + 1)]

print("Blah!")
```

Still prints the values `0, 2, 6, 12`! even though we only submitted the function to an executor list...

---

Fix it by moving the `for` loop block inside the context manager:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

def fnc(x, y):
    time.sleep(3)
    return x*y

futures = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
    for i in range(0, 4):
        print(f"Submitting {i}")
        futures += [executor.submit(fnc, i, i+1)]
    for f in futures:
        print(f.result())
```

Note that setting `max_workers=1` is essentially forcing the program to run consecutively rather than concurrently, in this program, setting `max_workers=X` will print the results of `X` returns of `fnc` at a time.

If you want to wait three seconds between each result, then either set `max_workers` to 1 or remove it at all. If you want to print two results at a time each three seconds - set `max_workers=2` etc..

Comment: Thread results will become available in the order in which they were submitted due to max_workers=1

Comment: @Pingu how come? when I set `max_workers=2` it just prints the results two at a time, in the correct order.. even if I make the `for` loop larger (going from `range(0, 100)`)

Comment: I think it's implied in the question that OP wants to be able to acquire a result as soon as **any** thread has finished. Of course, if there's only one worker then the threads will effectively execute synchronously - which rather defeats the point of threading

Comment: @Pingu See my updated comment, it does preserve the order

Comment: @Pingu I think it is implied in the question that the OP wants the preserve the order, and print `X` results at a time, when he sets `max_workers=1` then of course it will behave as a consecutive run, because in the example he gave, he wants `0, 2, 6, 12` - not `6, 2, 0, 12` etc..

Comment: For added context, the behavior I want is a loop that constructs a list/generator of futures, then also start processing each element using an expensive function (don't care how long each item takes, as long as I've secured the list).

Comment: @gamerz123123 Not sure I got your comment right - could you elaborate? or add an example in the question of what you're looking for in the output?